# PHP / nginx browsers difference: downloads file "Architecture 8th Edition.pdf" as "Architecture%208th%20Edition.pdf"

Tags: nginx

I am requesting file via PHP to be downloadeded from the webserver, on the webserver it is stored as LA6zneL.pdf for example, but the user has to obtain it with its original file name.
So I am calling this url

```
LA6zneL.pdf?f=William Stallings Computer Organization and Architecture 8th Edition.pdf
```

The user downloads it via Firefox/Safari/Opera with file name

```
William%20Stallings%20Computer%20Organization%20and%20Architecture%208th%20Edition.pdf
```

but in Chrome/Internet Explorer it is fine

```
William Stallings Computer Organization and Architecture 8th Edition.pdf
```

I don't know how it could be done via php? In my head just comes the solution to replace all ' ' chars with '-' for example in `f` parameter.

Here is the nginx config:

```
 add_header Content-Type "application/octet-stream";
 add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$arg_f";
```

Thanks for your time.

Btw. just found the same problem on ServerFault with no reply, hope someone will point me somewhere.
https://serverfault.com/questions/469837/how-to-send-file-names-with-spaces-to-user-with-nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

php:

```
$arg_f = base64_encode($arg_f);
```

Nginx

```
 add_header Content-Type "application/octet-stream";
 set_by_lua $filename "return ngx.decode_base64(ngx.var['arg_f'])";
 add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=\"$filename\"";
```